# angular - I have an element in the view bound to a variable in a service, but the view is not getting updated when the service is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable appList = [1,2,3] that is stored in a service. I import appList into the controller and bind it to the view in a list. I have a function  modifyAppList in the controller that calls a function of the same name in the service. This function is called with a button click in the view, and doing so definitely modifies the value in the service, as you can see with the console logs. I am very confused, because the view never updates even though the value in the service changes. If someone could take a look at the code and offer an explanation that would be much appreciated.

*NOTE* If you just change the contents of modifyAppList() to `appList[0] = 5; appList[1]= 6; appList[2]=7;` it will work as I expect. Something funny is happening when I assign appList to a new array inside of modifyAppList()

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
 .factory('appService', appService)

 function appService(){
  var appList = [1,2,3];
  var modifyList = [5,6,7];
  var modifyAppList = function(){ 
   console.log("At the beginning of modifyAppList: ", appList)  
   appList = [];
   console.log("After appList=[] : ", appList)
   for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    appList.push(modifyList[i]);
   }
   console.log("After modification: ", appList)


  }
  return {
   getAppList : function(){
    return appList;
   },
   modifyAppList : modifyAppList
  }
 }

angular
 .module('app')
 .controller('appCtrl', appCtrl)

 appCtrl.$inject = ['appService'];
 function appCtrl(appService){

  this.appList = appService.getAppList();
  this.modifyAppList = function(){
   appService.modifyAppList();
   var testList = appService.getAppList();
   console.log("After modification, and calling getList() : ", testList)
  }
 }
```

```html
<body ng-controller="appCtrl as vm">

 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="num in vm.appList" ng-bind="num"></li>
  </ul><br>
  <button ng-click="vm.modifyAppList()">modifyAppList()</button>
 

  <script src="controller.js"></script> 
  <script src="service.js"></script>
   

</body>
```

Comment: your fidddle is not working

Comment: Please make sure your fiddle is working, that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code in the service did `appList = [];`, it replaced the object reference with a new object reference. The object reference in the controller still points to the old array. (`appList = [];` literally means `appList = new Array();`)

To preserve the old reference, use `angular.copy`:

```
function appService(){
    var appList = [1,2,3];
    var modifyList = [5,6,7];
    var modifyAppList = function(){ 
        angular.copy(modifyList, appList);
    }
    return {
        getAppList : function(){
            return appList;
        },
        modifyAppList : modifyAppList
    }
}
```

From the Docs:

> ### angular.copy
>
> ### Usage
>
> `angular.copy(source, [destination]);`
>
> Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.
>
> - If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.

--[AngularJS `angular.copy` API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

Instead of replacing the array with a new array, `angular.copy` modifies the of the *contents* of the array. Changes to the array by the service will be seen by the controller and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected that was the problem, but didn't know the solution.

Comment: So I was mistakenly thinking that whatever is assigned to my variable will be bound to the view, but that's not really the case.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi once the service gets updated u haveent assign the value please check the link

JS

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope , appService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

        $scope.appList = appService.getAppList();
        $scope.modifyAppList = function(){
            console.log("After modification: ")
            appService.modifyAppList();
            var testList = appService.getAppList();
            $scope.appList = appService.getAppList();
            console.log("After modification, and calling getList() : ", testList)
        }
});
```

for ref https://plnkr.co/edit/XRAEwtiV9vdv0beiS5yU?p=preview

[image]

Comment: I know that approach will work, but I have another function that calls the service, the service modifies the bound variable and the view is automatically updated. I don't get why it's not happening here.

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the fact that I am reassigning appList to a new array in the function modifyAppList(). I changed modifyAppList() so that it directly changes the values, without assigning it to an empty array first and it works. So appList[0] = 5; appList[1]=6; appList[2]=7. You won't need to assign the value back as you say. The view will update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
appService.getAppList();
```

is not enough.
You have to apply it to the controller's scope:

```
this.appList = appService.getAppList();
```

As the variable appList inside your service has nothing to do with the one in the controller.

--update--

Well, the actual cause is the line in the service:

```
appList = [];
```

You indeed apply the appList to this.appList in the first line in the controller, but when you call the method modifyAppList another time, you apply a new empty array to it. Now the appList in the service is indeed has nothing to do with the old one.

So if you remove this line:

```
appList = [];
```

and change the follow line:

```
appList.push(modifyList[i]);
```

to something like this:

```
appList[i] = modifyList[i];
```

You will see it works well too. As you do not create a new reference this way.

Comment: If you look at the very first line in the controller function, the OP has already done exactly what you describe. This is not the issue.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the code. this.appList = appService.getAppList(); is the first line in my controller.

Comment: @Fluxionsdx , you did apply it at the beginning. But when you call modifyAppList add apply a new empty to appList, they are not the same reference any more. As a result, you have to bind it again.

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep things simple. Just ensure your `modifyAppList` function in `service` returns `appList`.

```
  var modifyAppList = function() {
    console.log("At the beginning of modifyAppList: ", appList)
    appList = [];
    console.log("After appList=[] : ", appList)
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      appList.push(modifyList[i]);
    }
    console.log("After modification: ", appList)

    return appList;
  }
```

Then in your Controller :

```
this.modifyAppList = function(){
  this.appList = appService.modifyAppList();
}
```

Comment: Because this is a simple abstraction of a larger problem and that approach wont work in my larger problem. I have one element in the view that I want to modify from multiple functions in multiple controllers.

Comment: Cool. @georgeawg answer was bang-on !